# An error on the chat system

Tags: bug, status-norepro

While chatting in the Incomprehensible room, I encountered this strange error.

[image]

The other chatters claim that they do not see the small white circle and its shadow. Is it a bug?

Edit: 
I found it again. This bug seems to pop up during night time. This one appeared at similar time to the other bug.

[image]

I inspected element, as Jarrod told me to.
This came out:

[image]

The spot disappeared later, even though I did not refresh.
Click on the image to make it bigger.

Comment: What is that image supposed to show?

Comment: It's most likely a wee network glitch somewhere on the way to your browser.  It's unlikely to cause cataclysm on a global scale.

Comment: It looks like one of those styrofoam crumbs that stick to a new monitor after you remove the packing.

Comment: @Robusto: If you can keep coming up with rationales like that, they should put you on the SE bug-resolution team! You could probably clear half the outstanding bugs without even needing to bother the developers!

Comment: Are you still seeing this? And you're using Chrome when this occurs?

Comment: @Jarrod Yes, I am using Chrome, but the spot disappeared.

Comment: Hmm, let me know if it returns.  And if it does, right-click it and "Inspect Element" to get more information about what it is!

Comment: @Jarrod It appeared Again!

Comment: Do you have the [Hover Zoom](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nonjdcjchghhkdoolnlbekcfllmednbl) browser extension installed?  That `#hzImg` element doesn't appear in our code.

Comment: @Jarrod I already have it installed. What do you mean element is not appearing in your code?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that it's not our chat software that is creating this issue, it's the Hover Zoom extension that is adversely interacting with chat.  I can only advise you to disable it for chat.

Comment: @Jarrod Aw, I wanted it to be much more serious then this.. :P
How does Hover Zoom affect this exactly?

Comment: I'm not sure, as I've never used it - I can only say we don't support third-party extensions. Sorry!